# Comparing the values of two arrays of type object

Tags: c#, arrays

At runtime I'm getting two different arrays `{object[10]}` and I would like to check if the values in the first array are the same as those in the other. The actual types of the elements could be `string`, `int` or `bool`. For example element `[1] = "Test"` and element `[2] = 3` and so on.

What I've done is this:

```
  for (var j = 0; j < newData.ItemArray.Length; j++)
  {
    if (newData.ItemArray[j].ToString().ToLower() != originalData.ItemArray[j].ToString().ToLower())
    {
      isModified = true;
      break;
    }
  }
```

I can't say that I'm satisfied with this solution, however it seems to work judging by the few tests I made. However I feel that there should be a better way for doing this.

ADDITIONAL
Judjing from the comments maybe I wasn't too clear in my question. This is what I get as input:

[image]

I expect the other array to contains the same data. The only problem is that all elements are stored as objects. So for example I would like to know if element `[3]` in the first array is like element `[3]` from the another array. Ideally I would like to compare two boolean values but since everything is stored as objects I'm looking for ideas how to check if the values are the same or for example from `[1] = "Training"` in the other array is `[1] = "Not Training"` and so on..

Comment: Override the `Object Equals(this Object object)` method and compare each property.

Comment: @Leron: I've just asked because of your  bad example with only strings. That's why i've modified it

Comment: If there is an string like "1" and an integer with value 1 (just as an example) your function will return an ok incorrectly.

Comment: Bear in mind that if string case is important then this will fail because "FOO" = "foo"

Comment: If you don't mind LINQ: [SequenceEqual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb348567(v=vs.110).aspx) should work for primitive types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you use [`ItemArray`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.itemarray(v=vs.110).aspx) i'm pretty sure that it's the property of `DataRow` which returns a `Object[]` of all fields of this row. So you  want to compare two datarows with each other.

You can use [`SequenceEqual`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
bool isModifed = !newData.ItemArray.SequenceEqual(originalData.ItemArray);
```

This  compares strings case-sensitively as opposed to your approach.

If you want to ignore the case:

```
isModifed = !newData.ItemArray.Select(obj => obj?.ToString())
    .SequenceEqual(originalData.ItemArray.Select(obj => obj?.ToString())
        , StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

Comment: `SequenceEquals()` will compare using `Equals` operator which in most cases ( for user defined types ) will not be overwritten meaning the comparison will fail.

Comment: You are exactly right, I am comparing `DataRows`. But the elements in the `ItemArray` are the ones that I really would like to compare.

Comment: @Leron: and that is what SequenceEqual does :)

Comment: @m.rogalski: it is overwritten for all types that are supported in a DataTable (apart from `Byte[]`). If you want to support a custom type you either have to override Equals+GetHashCode or pass a custom `IEqualityComparer<T>` to `SequenceEqual`. You can implement your own or use an available like i did in the second example.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I had issues with `SequenceEquals()` with user defined types that's why I wrote this comment. Now your edited answer looks like it can handle most of the cases ( or even all ).

Comment: @TimSchmelter Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks